# how to update the state if dropdown has selected value with Hooks and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm learning the react js and have a situation where I need to update the state when dropdown has a default value, I'm able to set the state on change event but don't know what to do if the first option is selected.

[Here is the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-water-hjj82?file=/src/App.js)

Code:

```
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => setMyValue(e.target.value)}
        defaultValue={myValue}
      >
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
      </select>
      <h2>
        {" "}
        You selected{" "}
        <span style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>{myValue}</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

how can I set "myValue" to option1 when a form is submitted?

Many thanks!

Comment: You have two options to fix this. You can add an empty option `<option></option>` or you can change the default state to option 1 using `useState("Option 1")`

Comment: I tried a second fix. but on form submit seems the default selected option is not set.
what if having dynamic value

Answer (score 1):

you can set the options in an array and then set the state as the value of the first entry of the array. This way the state can stay dynamic , meaning the array can change and always the first entry will be the first selection.

```
  const options = ["options 1", "option 2", "option 3"];
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(options[0]);

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => setMyValue(e.target.value)}
        defaultValue={myValue}
      >
        {options.map((option, idx) => (
          <option key={idx}>{option}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <h2>
        {" "}
        You selected{" "}
        <span style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>{myValue}</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
)
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropdown-using-hook-forked-1kf9e?file=/src/App.js